# Best practice to dynamically choose view model based on dynamic variable using the same Aurelia route?

Tags: aurelia

I know that Aurelia route modules can be specified dynamically using `navigationStrategy` but that does not work for my purposes because the toggle value resides in the RouterConfiguration that only runs once. I need a way to route to different views where the toggle value can change multiple times during one session. Additionally, not all routes have multiple views.

What is the best practice for routing to different views on the same route based on a dynamic value?

I've come up with a few different strategies but I'm not sure which one is the most acceptable way to do this.

- Using `viewPorts` where the route will have a static `moduleId` to a view that injects the name into an instance of `<router-view name="view1_index"></router-view>` using a global string, e.g. 'view1' may be passed down as 'view2', etc.
- Using 2 or more instances of `<compose>` where the route will again have a static `moduleId` to a view that will use a global variable to toggle an `if.bind` in the `<compose>` instances
- Using `canActivate` in the route module and redirecting to the secondary viewport if conditions are met
- Using a pipeline step in the router config to evaluate whether it should direct to a different module (if this is possible)

Which of these strategies, if any, is most accepted? If all of these are odd ways of routing to different views per route, what should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best practice for routing to different views on the same
>   route based on a dynamic value?

Compose is your best bet. It is common to pass a parameter to the route, capture the parameter in the `activate(params)` callback, set a variable on your view model using the params, and then use that variable to set the `view-model` attribute of `<compose>`.

> Using a pipeline step in the router config to evaluate whether it
>   should direct to a different module (if this is possible)

This is very possible. A common use case is authentication, where you use the `AuthorizeStep` to check whether a user is authorized and redirect him away if he is not. See http://foreverframe.net/exploring-aurelia-pipelines/. This can be activated in the `PreactivateStep` as well.

> Using viewPorts where the route will have a static moduleId to a view
>   that injects the name into an instance of  using a global string, e.g. 'view1'
>   may be passed down as 'view2', etc.

I recommend against using viewports for anything other than associating routes to views on a certain section of the screen.

**Edit:**

A third option you might be interested in is returning a `Redirect` from your `canActivate()` function.

```
import { Redirect } from 'aurelia-router';

canActivate(params) {
  let thing = this.thing = await this.service.getById(params.id);
  if (!thing) {
    return new Redirect('somewhere');
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to avoid adding an extra parameter that appears in the route itself. There isn't a way to pass a hidden parameter and consume it in `activate()` correct? It seems to me that with `compose` I'm giving the module control over "routing" in a sense. However, I could not find a way in a `PreActivateStep` to retrieve information about the next route so I'm not sure how to evaluate from there.

Comment: Correct, and it wouldn't be good design. The activation lifecycle is all about mapping routes to view/view-model pairs, and the activate(params) callback is for reading dynamic info directly from the route. You might also consider returning a redirect from canActivate. I'll update my answer.